Upper bound for distribution function for variable with zero expectation.
A problem from final Year 1 probability exam.
Is it true for any random variable $Y$ s.t. $E[Y]=0$ and $E[Y^2]<\infty$ that:
$P(Y>x)\leq\frac{E[Y^2]}{E[Y^2]+x}$ ?
I thought we can rewrite it like this:
$P(Y\leq x)\geq\frac{x}{E[Y^2]+x}$
$P(Y\leq x)\geq\frac{1}{\frac{E[Y^2]}{x}+1}$
$P(Y\leq x)(\frac{E[Y^2]}{x}+1) \geq 1$
If $x\geq 1$, then $x\geq\sqrt{x}$ and $P(Y\leq x) \geq P(Y\leq \sqrt{x})$, so
$P(Y\leq x)(\frac{E[Y^2]}{x}+1) \geq P(Y\leq \sqrt{x})(\frac{E[Y^2]}{x}+1)$
By Chebyshev’s inequality,
$P(Y\leq \sqrt{x})(\frac{E[Y^2]}{x}+1)\geq P(Y\leq \sqrt{x})(P(|Y|>\sqrt{x})+1)= F_Y(\sqrt{x})(2-F_Y(\sqrt{x})+F_Y(-\sqrt{x}-0)) \geq F_Y(\sqrt{x})(2-F_Y(\sqrt{x})) \geq 1 $ ($x(2-x)$ has minimum at $x=1$).
However nothing beautiful occurs when $x < 1$.

This is called the one-sided  Chebyshev inequality or Cantelli's inequality.
